# plot count of values by factor in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

New to R, stuck googling this (probably easy) thing for too long.

I want to plot the proportion of males that fathered offspring, according to whether they have a nest or not. (I don't want the information of how many offspring they fathered). This is my dataset called "males"

```
fishID nest off
fish1    1  25
fish2    0   0
fish3    0   5
fish4    1  15
fish5    1   0
fish6    0   2
fish7    0   0
fish8    1   4
```

I've used the following code to change the values of offspring to 0 and 1 (though this feels clumsy already)...

```
#converts the values in offspring to 0 and 1s
vars=c("off")
males[males$off != "0", vars]="1"
males
```

...and I can plot proportions using...

```
ggplot(males,aes(x = males$nest,fill = males$off)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

...but I would like to colour them so that 0 (no nest) is one colour and 1 (nest) is another colour, then the proportion of males that didn't father offspring is a paler version of each colour. The above produces colours according to "offspring", irrespective of "nest".

Tips welcome.
 (Mac OS X, R 3.0.3 GUI 1.63 Snow Leopard build (6660))

Comment: `males$off <- factor(as.numeric(males$off != 0))`

Comment: thank you, adding that to my growing library.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)

males$nest <- as.factor(males$nest)
males$off <- as.factor(males$off)

ggplot(males, aes(x = nest, fill = off)) + 
geom_bar(width = 0.25) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c('green', 'darkgreen'))
```

[image]

Comment: Almost... I would like the two columns to be coloured according to if they have a nest or not e.g. 0 nest, green and light green, 1 nest, blue and light blue.

Answer (score 1):

Done it! Thank you. It was the fill by interaction I was missing.

```
require(ggplot2)

males$off <- factor(as.numeric(males$off != 0))
males$nest <- as.factor(males$nest)

ggplot(males, aes(x = nest, fill = interaction(males$nest, males$off))) + geom_bar(width = 0.25) + scale_fill_manual(values = c('deepskyblue3', 'tomato3', 'deepskyblue', 'tomato'))
```

(Eventually needed the same number of lines of code as days googling...)